# Perguntas pedindo indicação de material estão no escopo?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Algumas vezes quis fazer perguntas pedindo indicações de material (livros, videos, etc) para estudar algum assunto  mas fiquei em dúvida se esse tipo de pergunta é considerada no escopo do site. Alguns sites da rede aceitam esse tipo de perguntas, outros tem restrições. No SOpt isso é considerado dentro do escopo ou não?

Comment: Esse tipo de conteúdo geralmente fica na wiki da tag `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/<linguagem|framework|tecnologia/info`. Você perguntar por indicações de materias no chat.

Comment: Reforço o que o @perdeu escreveu. Wiki da Tag e Chat são ótimos lugares para esse tipo de conteúdo. Concordo também com a boa resposta o bigown, que explica o mesmo e traz à luz do dia problemas reais que têm havido.

Answer (score 8):

A comunidade mostra com clareza que não.

Essencialmente isto responde o que você deseja saber. Vou aproveitar a oportunidade e mais abaixo falarei mais do assunto para os usuários do site como um todo, já que o assunto ainda não foi definitivamente estabelecido de forma orgânica como deveria ser.

## Local adequado

O comentário do @perdeu acima mostra onde este conteúdo deve estar. O *chat* pode ser usado para pedir para alguém colocar novas informações lá. Se isto ocorrer através de uma pergunta tudo bem, mas ela deve ser fechada sem seguida.

## O que estamos vendo aqui no *site*

Mas a SE de vez em quando encasqueta com alguma coisa e obriga ficar no *site* mesmo que seja contrário ao que as pessoas que fazem deste *site* o sucesso que é não querem que este tipo de pergunta fique aqui. Afinal este é um *site* de Q&A e não um diretório de *links*. É triste ver que que a SE desrespeita a vontade da comunidade representativa e o próprio mecanismo que ela desenvolveu para forçar sua vontade sem medir as consequências.

## Regras de outros *sites*

Na verdade nenhum *site* da rede aceita efetivamente este tipo de conteúdo. Existem alguns que por decisão da comunidade e não por imposição da SE aceitam alguma coisa com restrições, onde há comprometimento de ser um conteúdo gerido pela comunidade para garantir que não fique com baixa qualidade e não se prolifere em uma miríade de bobagens. Existem casos em que alguma coisa assim acaba passando. Por isto é estranho que a SE venha impor sua vontade justamente aqui. Sem fazer o mesmo em outros *sites*. pelo contrário, a SE já compro briga enorme para que isto não fosse considerado conteúdo de qualidade.

## Respeito à comunidade

Havia um tempo que a SE era democrática e ainda nos outros *sites* vemos isto. Hoje ela tem atitudes desrespeitosas com as pessoas que se dedicam ao *site* para atender seus interesses e interesses pontuais de quem não está comprometido com *site*. Falta o reconhecimento real e não apenas no discurso que essas pessoas fazem o *site*, para o bem ou pra mal, essa pessoas viabilizam o *site*. E ficar chamando essas pessoas de preconceituosas, ignorantes, ceguetas, obcecadas, medrosas e outros adjetivos nada abonadores (como pode ser visto em diversos pontos deste ou outros *sites* da rede) e que muitos acham que poderiam muito bem ser aplicados à algumas pessoas da SE, é um tapa da cara de quem poderia estar fazendo outra coisa mas gasta seu tempo aqui produzindo conteúdo relevante.

Todos os regimes ditatoriais dizem estar fazendo o bem para a comunidade em nome de uma maioria silenciosa. Eles dizem saber o que as pessoas querem baseados em 3 ou 4 pessoas que dizem exatamente o que o ditador quer ouvir. O ditador escolhe um rumo sem ouvir a comunidade, ouvindo apenas as pessoas que concordam com ele para parecer que está sendo sendo democrático. O ditadores sempre se esforçam para parecerem democráticos e vão deturpar até a matemática para "provar" que estão fazendo o bem para todos.

O dia que a **comunidade**, de verdade, mostrar que quer este tipo de conteúdo, eu apoiarei, mesmo ainda discordando.

## Ações da comunidade X reações da SE

Eu sei que nem todo mundo concorda com isto mas muitos concordam. Isto precisa ficar claro. No discurso a comunidade será o que ela quer ser, na prática estamos vendo que será o que a SE quer, mesmo que ela não esteja nos pagando nada para estar aqui e servir aos seus interesses.

Reforço que a SE chega deturpar seu próprio mecanismo, suas próprias mediadas do que cada um pode fazer, os próprios pesos que ela estabeleceu na criação da plataforma e deu poderes aos que ela julga merecedores, usando argumentos falaciosos (até postando *links* sobre o assunto porque quem você sabe "quem diz primeiro que o outro é falacioso está dizendo a verdade") para "provar" um ponto em que todas as atitudes dela mesmo na rede mostram que ela não pensa assim. E mesmo que ela estivesse 100% certa no que ela quer, ainda assim seria uma imposição contrária ao que as pessoas demonstraram em seus julgamentos conforme o mecanismo permite e deveria ser respeitado. Afinal **se** tivesse havido um erro, ele foi de julgamento (que sempre pode ser questionado mas não deveria ser desrespeitado) e não um erro de direito (ação não relacionado ao fato). Mesmo que seja um erro da comunidade, é um erro dela e não um erro de quem não faz o *site* ter todo esse conteúdo. Nós como comunidade sabemos o que é bom para nós. Nós nos esforçarmos para ter este direito. Assim como outras comunidades da rede têm suas vontades são respeitadas.

De fato todas informações no *site* produzidas pela comunidade ou mesmo pela SE na Central de Ajuda caminham para a indicação clara que este tipo de pergunta não é adequada. Mesmo que alguns discordem não parece ser a vontade da maioria dos usuários mais representativos.

Todos estamos aqui para ajudar, estamos fazendo algo que resolve defeitos de outros *sites* da rede, mas tudo tem um limite, não estamos aqui para reproduzir o que existe em fóruns desqualificados como tantos outros por aí. Acho que a maioria que se dedica aqui o faz porque sempre viu esta plataforma como algo diferente, algo que pode tornar a internet realmente melhor e não porque atende qualquer interesse sem análise da qualidade. Acho que muitos aqui não querem ver a proliferação de perguntas que pedem implícita ou explicitamente por respostas acéfalas.

Answer (score 4):

Tentando responder pontualmente ao seu pedido de suporte:

## Há controvérsias

Isso você já deve ter percebido ao ler as outras respostas. O tema é sensível e dá muita margem a discussões. Só que a discussão aqui vai além do que você perguntou, e tem a ver com a história do SOpt – que, apesar de jovem, já tem praticamente um ano de vida e acumulou uma certa bagagem, para o bem e para o mal.

## Se você pretende pedir recomendação

- Não faça perguntas do tipo "estou querendo aprender [linguagem/biblioteca], quais [livros/tutoriais/sites] vocês recomendam?"
- Mostre ao máximo o que você já sabe. Detalhe o que você quer saber. Quanto mais focada for a sua pergunta, menor a chance de qualquer resposta servir (e se qualquer resposta serve, nenhuma serve).
- Saiba que tem todo tipo de gente lendo e avaliando a sua pergunta. Tem os que vão seguir a primeira coisa que disserem sobre ela, e tem os que irão avaliar a pergunta pelo que ela é, mesmo que se encaixe em alguma categoria-tabu tipicamente rejeitada. Na minha experiência, se a pergunta for bem construída e demonstrar esforço de reflexão, ela tende a ser aceita, ainda que se enquadre como exceção a alguma regra.
- Tenha em mente que existe uma disputa sobre esse tipo de pergunta, e que apesar de todos os seus esforços sua pergunta pode acabar pega no meio do tiroteio. Se isso acontecer, não é nada pessoal.

Answer (score 2):

## O problema com pedidos de materiais e links

Material adequado para estudo varia muito de acordo com:

- A **pessoa**: alguns preferem ler, outros assistir a vídeo-aulas
- A **situação**: trabalho, estudo
- A **localidade**: alguns preferem Inglês, outros dependem de tradução
- O **objetivo**: resolver um problema específico, conhecer algo de forma abrangente
- A **data**: versões das ferramentas, novos materiais existentes

Então, perguntas dessa natureza *geralmente* são ruins porque novos usuários tendem a refazer a pergunta frequentemente por considerarem seu caso particular diferente dos demais.

Além disso, geralmente essas perguntas são muito mal elaboradas e isso atrai respostas de baixíssima qualidade.

## Casos limítrofes

Por outro lado, do meu ponto de vista há perguntas sobre "como aprender X" que realmente valem a pena.

Existem tecnologias, ferramentas, frameworks, linguagens que realmente são complicados de se entender e praticamente todo programador humilde reconhece que é complicado trilhar o caminho das pedras. Nesses casos, uma pergunta bem feita e respostas de pessoas com experiência podem ser salva-vidas para muita gente.

Na minha opinião, se houver possibilidade de criar uma referência útil e duradoura sobre o assunto a pergunta torna-se viável. Existem certos livros e materiais que são sempre a resposta certa para determinados problemas. Porém nem sempre há especialistas suficientes sobre os tópicos para criar e manter as referências adequadas.

## Outros sites

Sim, existem outros sites que aceitam ou toleram perguntas com indicação de materiais, livros e referências. Isso ocorre muito nos que não são de exatas ou que são focados em ferramentas ou tecnologias específicas.

Se você analisar vários desses sites verá que existem perguntas desse tipo e até parecidas umas com as outras, porém algumas fechadas e outras não. Isso vai depender se há uma ou mais pessoas da comunidade que se importam de alguma forma em fechá-la ou mantê-la, também depende muito de sua formulação e do quanto o tema é interessante para os usuários.

No entanto, esse tipo de pergunta provavelmente não vai estar na página de "escopo" do site. O escopo é escrito pela equipe do SE para aquilo que ela espera ser o foco principal do site. Por mais que seja um norte, o comportamento final do site será a definida pela comunidade. Se a ideia fosse segui-lo à risca, então eliminaríamos qualquer possibilidade de desenvolvimento por parte da comunidade.

## Sobre a atuação dos funcionários da rede Stack Exchange

Houve casos, tanto aqui como em outros sites, de atuação dos funcionários da SE que desagradaram uma parcela da comunidade ativa. Acho importante dialogar, questionar e apresentar pontos contrários e críticas comedidas. Mas falar em *ditadura* aqui é um completo absurdo, nem vou entrar em detalhes sobre isto porque é totalmente *nonsense*.

Nem sempre é possível chegar a um consenso que deixe todos plenamente felizes, mas é essencial saber conviver com as diferenças e com as decisões alheias, mesmo que falhas. Felizmente, até agora não houve um caso que prejudicasse a comunidade num sentido mais amplo ou modificasse enfaticamente seu comportamento.

Além disso, nunca houve, não haverá e nem se deve esperar consenso dentro da SE sobre como lidar com cada situação. Os próprios criadores, Joel Spolsky e Jeff Atwood, sempre discordaram em vários pontos sobre este e outros assuntos. Imagine se colocarmos na equação todos os outros gerentes e desenvolvedores.

Particularmente, falando aqui especificamente sobre a divergência de opiniões, considero isso é completamente saudável. Se houvesse uma diretriz absoluta e que não pudesse ser questionada, aí sim isso seria considerado imposição. Eu vou começar a me preocupar quando tivermos uma só voz em todo o site, sem discordâncias.

O que eu tenho entendido sobre as ações gerais da SE (não estou dizendo que concordo com elas) é a tentativa de tornar os sites da rede um pouco mais inclusivos. O SOen já sofreu muito com conteúdo ruim, só que o mesmo ocorre por excesso de zelo e falta de trato com novos usuários. Muitos veem isso como se agora devêssemos "aceitar qualquer lixo", mas isto é simplesmente um exagero. Eu acho que a SE tem mais medo de que nos tornemos rapidamente uma comunidade desgastada como o SOen do que efetivamente em ter algumas perguntas de baixa qualidade no site.

## O outro lado da moeda

Desde o início do beta nós dissemos que iríamos estabelecer os nossos próprios limites. Mas, infelizmente, tenho visto na maioria das vezes esses limites apenas retrocedendo. Na prática, nós simplesmente não fizemos nada de muito diferente. Nós tivemos sucesso em muitos aspectos, mas ainda somos em muitos deles uma cópia aperfeiçoada do SOen.

Note que não estou falando sobre aceitar tudo, estou apenas constatando algo para que cada um faça sua auto-crítica.

Tudo isso é demonstrado por algo que vem ocorrendo repetidamente (e aqui falo com propriedade): perguntas fechadas rapidamente, comentários rudes, acompanhados de falta de instrução ao AP e quase nenhum esforço em compreender o problema.

Para quem já faz parte do site, é muito mais fácil passar por cima disso, votar para fechar, dar uma "instrução" do tipo "pesquise no google" ou "aprenda a escrever" ao AP e seguir com a vida. Mas tudo isso não é bom para novos usuários, nem para o site como um todo.

No último sábado, falei sobre o Stack Overflow em Português para um grupo de estudantes em São Paulo. Expliquei como o site funciona, sobre o modelo de Q&A, como fazer uma pergunta, como responder e convidei-os a participar.

Porém, algo que as pessoas sempre comentam sobre o SO, e não podemos negar isso, é a dificuldade de começar a participar no site, principalmente quem tem pouco conhecimento. Os novatos não sabem como escrever no estilo aceito pela comunidade, nem conseguem elaborar uma pergunta com excelência. Mas de que adianta o esforço para fazer o site crescer se os novatos não duram 5 minutos?

É triste acompanhar casos onde novos usuários foram mal recebidos e ter a certeza de que nunca mais participariam do site. Tudo isso em prol de manter a "qualidade" e ficar dentro do "escopo", como se isso fosse justificativa para não ser amigável.

Eu mesmo passei exatamente por essa situação ainda no beta privado. Demorou até eu pegar o jeito, tempos depois minha reputação de alguma forma começou a "resolver" isso, infelizmente, já que a reputação não faz com que eu esteja mais certo ou errado hoje do que há 9 meses. Mas para um "desconhecido", basta um único usuário postar um comentário ou voto negativo ou sinalizar algo para desencadear o processo. Isso já melhorou bastante, mas sabemos que ainda há "robôs" que votam como rebanho e que na fila de análise aprovam praticamente tudo que veem pela frente.

Enfim, se você é um usuário ativo do site e já "salvou" uma pergunta ruim que estava fadada ao fechamento ou exclusão, você deve ser capaz de compreender o que estou dizendo. O mesmo vale para quem começou do "zero" e consegue lembrar das barreiras que precisou superar.

Comment: Como você chama a ação de uma pessoa tomar uma atitude sem diálogo, sem ouvir o que uma parcela significativa da comunidade está dizendo? E elas estão dizendo no que fazem no dia-a-dia do *site*. Se você tiver que escolher quem você vai ter que deixar feliz, quem você escolhe? Justamente saber conviver com as diferenças é não fazer o que foi feito no *site*, impondo uma coisa que claramente vai contra o que alguns querem. E isto foi feito de acordo com as regras do *site*. Aqui não tem excesso de zelo, aqui somos extramente inclusivos. Eu sempre defendi isto desde o primeiro dia.

Comment: Mas tudo tem limite. Mas mesmo se for para não ter limite, ok pra mim, desde que seja uma decisão da comunidade, das pessoas que fazem este *site*. Eu você e todos os que queiram participar dizendo o que pensamos e respeitando a decisão de todos. Não haverá consenso. Mas haverá uma decisão democrática. Exatamente como tivemos nas eleições brasileiras agora. Uma decisão que desagradou uma parte expressiva da população feito de uma forma forma até questionável, mas que no fim do processo a decisão é respeitada. É só isto que eu desejaria.

Comment: Houve uma diretriz vinda da SE e qualquer questionamento é refutado sem argumentos plausíveis, pelo contrário, com argumentos incoerentes com a própria postura da SE como um tudo. Poder falar mas não poder decidir não muda nada. "Desde o início do beta nós dissemos que iríamos estabelecer os nossos próprios limites. Mas, infelizmente, tenho visto na maioria das vezes esses limites apenas retrocedendo.". Exatamente é aí que eu pego a questão da ditadura. É algo como: "se fizerem o que eu quero, eu sou democrático, caso contrário, eu vou impor porque eu é que sei o que é certo".

Comment: Aí no final há algo completamente diferente do que eu estou falando. Tudo isto eu concordo, só não podemos deixar de fazer o que precisa ser feito em nome da inclusão. Então a única questão que há discordâncias é se vamos aceitar perguntas que não são perguntas definidas pela própria SE na Central de Ajuda e em *posts* que ela mesma continua usando nos *sites* atualmente para justificar suas ações. Eu cobro que a se a SE quer mudar alguma coisa que seja coerente. Se maioria não quer isto, paciência.

Comment: A SE conquistou bons usuários permitindo que eles determinem o que é bom para eles, não impondo para eles o que ela acha. E o que ela sempre achou e oficialmente ainda acha é o mesmo que estamos querendo. Inclusivo acho que a maioria aceita bem o fato de ser mais amigável. Mas isto pode ser feito à qualquer preço. Porque aí é aceitar tudo. Porque fechar uma ou outra pergunta ruim (estou falando apenas dessas que a SE resolveu polemizar) vai tornar o *site* menos amigável?

Comment: Mas aceitar torna a porta aberta para aceitar uma miríade de perguntas iguais que não trazem conteúdo relevante para o *site*. Eu não entendo porque a SE quer insistir tanto nessas perguntas. Tem outras que ela poderia mudar e conseguir apoio e ser mais importante para tornar o *site* amigável. Eu acho que tanto a SE, quanto os usuários precisam decidir logo o que querem. A SE deve dizer que vai exigir da comunidade a postura que ela determinar. E a comunidade precisa dizer se vai aceitar isto ou não.